# Thread safe getter of a value that never changes

Tags: c++, thread-safety

Is it safe to access class members from diffent threads simultaneously without mutexes if the value never changes? A value is simple pointer, so creating a copy has no effect on the original value. You can assume that `B` class itself is thread safe. `A` class can have other members, access to them will be syncronized using a mutex.

```
class A {
public:
  A() { value = new B(); }

  // thread safe?
  B* get_value() { return value; }

private:
  B* value; //never changes

}
```

Comment: The real issue is, can you trust your user not to change it?

Comment: Yes, it's safe, any specific concerns why you think it might be unsafe?

Comment: @OMGtechy can user somehow break the program if they can't change `A` code?

Comment: I'll write up a possible scenario in an answer for you :)

Comment: Done, let me know if anything's not clear!

Comment: The only possible problem I can see is ensuring the initialisation happens-before the read. In a real program that would probably naturally be the case, but if you're playing a bit fast and loose with synchronisation it might be an issue.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is clear and shows a certain understanding of the underlying issues. Upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

You have an instance of `A` called `foo`:

```
A foo;
```

You call `foo`'s `get_value()` function and store the result in a variable called `bar`:

```
auto bar = foo.get_value();
```

This in itself is perfectly fine, but suppose the user modifies the value pointed to by `bar`?

```
*bar = B();
```

The address stored in `bar` could be copied all over the program. All these copies can now modify the value pointed to by `B` inside your class `A` however they wish, whenever they wish.

Comment: This does not affect `foo`'s `value` pointer and hence does not break thread safety. `B` class is responsible for its own thread safety, of course, but `A`'s getter is totally fine.

Comment: How so? You're obtaining a pointer to a value, and the value pointed to by it can potentially be altered by anyone?

Comment: That would be change of referenced data (value), and not the never changed pointer to this data stored in A class.

Comment: This is what I thought the OP meant. :)

Comment: He says "You can assume that B class itself is thread safe.", which means it's `=` operator can be assumed to be safe as well.

Comment: Ah, missed that bit. I'll leave this answer up anyway, but it seems that, assuming B **is** thread safe, the code is fine as you say.